# Constructing a certain sort of short exact sequence

Tags: group-theory

If I have a group $N$ and an automorphism $\phi$ of it such that $\phi^n$ is inner (suppose by conjugation by $x \in N$) and $\phi(x)=x$, how can I prove that there is a group $G$ that fits into the short exact sequence

$1 \rightarrow N \rightarrow G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow 1$

and meets the following four conditions, for some $y \in G$:

i) $y$ acts on $N$ by $\phi$

ii)the image of $y$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and

iii) $y^n=x$ ?

I've tried to play with the semidirect product $N \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ as I have a hunch that it'll be fruitful, but I'm honestly not sure how to do this. Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think that you can only do this if you assume that $\phi(x)=x$, that is, (i) needs to be a hypothesis rather than a conclusion. It is not true that every automorphism $\phi$ of every group $N$ for which $\phi^n$ is conjugation by some $x \in N$ satisfies $\phi(x)=x$. Or perhaps you have missed out some other assumption?

Comment: The claim would also be true under the extra assumption $Z(N)=1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, that is what I meant. I will edit the question.

Comment: @DerekHolt Do you have any hints as to this question?